# Principal Planes and Principal Stresses

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, stresses

Consider that a state of plane stress exists at a point and the stresses acting on an element taken at that point are given as,

[image]

The normal stress acting at any plane of this element inclined at an angle $\theta$ (+ve when measured antickw from horizontal) is given by the stress transformation equation

[image]

To determine the principal stresses we first need to determine the location of them, i.e. the $\theta$ for them, this can be done by equating the derivative of above equation w.r.t $\theta$ to  zero to obtain

$$\tan 2\theta=\frac{2\tau_{xy}}{\sigma_x-\sigma_y}$$

The values of $\theta$ which satisfy the above equation are

[image]

i.e. these are the values of $\theta$ for which $\sigma_{\theta}$ can be either minimum or maximum.

> For instance, at $\theta_1$ the normal stress could be either minimum
> or maximum, if it is max then $\theta_3$ value will give the same max
> value, and then $\theta_2$ and $\theta_4$ will give the minimum normal
> stress.

**We however do not know if  $\theta_1$ would give us the maximum nomral stress or minimum normal stress**

My Trouble starts from here: If I put $\theta_1$ in the stress transformation equation i.e. in the equation for $\sigma_{\theta}$ then I get

$$\sigma_{\theta_1} = {\sigma_{x} + \sigma_{y} \over 2} +
\sqrt{ \left( {\sigma_{x} - \sigma_{y} \over 2} \right)^2 + \tau_{xy}^2 }$$

which is the expression for maximum normal stress (principal stress $\sigma_1)$. This equation tell us that we are getting maximum normal stress at $\theta_1$. However, I solved some numerical problems on the same topic and when I found $\theta_1$, the maximum normal stress wasn't coming in its plane but rather in $\theta_2$  plane. (the numerical problem is given below)

I found this query is somewhat difficult to explain, I did my best to explain the problem, if the question makes sense to anyone please help. Thank You.

---

The numerical problem that I attempted:

### [image]

Trying to better explain my problem -

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd best put the numerical examples you tried, so that its more clear. The first value is indeed the angle, especially if you use **atan2** instead of **atan**. Additionally, I think there is some confusion over the minimum and maximum values with respect to the normal stresses. At the principal direction one the normal stresses is maximum $\sigma_1$ and the other is minimum $\sigma_2$ .  At the 45 degrees plane the normal stresses in x and y are equal ($\frac{\sigma_1+\sigma_2}{2}$)  and the shear stress is maximum.

Comment: I think there is mistake in your expressions of the angle for the max and min normal stresses. Are you familiar with Mohr's Circle method for stress analysis?

Comment: @NMech Done. Please look if it is making better sense now. I have also made some changes in the previous version of the ques.

Comment: @r13 Oh, what mistake though? The values of theta that I have given, do satisfy the equation of $tan2\theta$. The values of normal stress  on $\theta_3$ and $\theta_4$ will be the same as that obtained for 1 and 2, respectively. Yes, I'm familiar with Mohr's Circle, but was trying to obtain results analytically.

Answer (score 1):

This is to illustrate my confusion over your question, which I've no clear clue what it is about.

[image]

Per the given stresses and orientation of the element, the sketch below shows the results and the rotation of the principal axes with respect to the original position.

[image]

Comment: r13, since for the value $\theta_1$ the normal stress could be either a max or a min, i expect when I put $\theta_1$ in $\sigma_{\theta}$ , it should yield two values of normal stress i.e., one for $\sigma_1$ and other for $\sigma_2$ , but I only get one value i.e. of $\sigma_1$. Perhaps, I'm doing some mistake in math, there should be a $\pm$ that must pop up somewhere

Comment: Not the math, it is the misunderstanding of the word - "Either", one out of two possibilities. "The value θ1 the normal stress **could be either** a max or a min," which needs to be verified by the general equation. Once determined, the min stress is on the axis 90 degrees from it, and at the opposite end, there is another max with angle = theta1 + 180 degrees. All are clearly indicated on the sketch.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the problem is summarised in this:

> "Since for the value θ1 the normal stress could be either a max or a min, i expect when I put θ1 in σθ , it should yield two values of normal stress i.e., one for σ1 and other for σ2 , but I only get one value i.e. of σ1.

In the problem above you calculated that the angle $\theta_1$ is 23.7 degrees (there is a small error in your solution -- you mention 27.3).

This angle is with one of the principal axis and its complementary angle $\theta_2$ is between angle $x$ and the other principal axis $x_2$. i.e. $\theta_2 = 90- \theta_1= 66.3 deg$

If you plug $\theta_1$ to the stress transformation equation you get -41.6 MPa,  but if you plug $\theta_2 $ you will end up with 116.4 MPa.

---

The transformation equation you are using is only giving you the normal stress at a direction $\theta$ from the current coordinate system.  So you need to apply them at different angles to get different values.

There is a more generic form of those equations which allows for converting from coordinate system xy to x'y', given that the later is rotated by $\theta$. See below for said equations.

[image]