# Orientation of Principal planes with respect to plane maximum shear

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

Consider that the state of plane stress at a point is given by the following element

[image]

We obtain principal planes and planes of maximum shear at different orientations of the plane, where the orientation is given by the angle $\theta$ that the outward normal of that plane makes with the horizontal in the anticlockwise sense.

I read that the plane of maximum shear and principal planes come at 45° angle to each other.

I was interested in knowing whether the principal plane is at a larger value of $\theta$ or the plane of maximum shear?

I.e. if

$\theta_p$ = The angle that a principal plane makes with the horizontal measured anticlockwise

$\theta_s$ = The angle that plane of Max shear makes with horizontal measured anticlockwise

Then, is

$\theta_p$ - $\theta_s$ = 45°

Or

$\theta_s$ - $\theta_p$ = 45°

i.e. will the plane of Max shear lie ahead of principal plane or the other way round?

[image]

Comment: If you understand the answers here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/50335/10902 then you should be able to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- $\theta_p$ = The angle that a principal plane makes with the horizontal measured anticlockwise

then you would get the principal stress values $\sigma_1, sigma_2$. I find it easier to use the following illustration for the principal stresses (its equivalent to yours but to me a rotated coordinate system is more intuitive).

[image]

Also you should get the same principal stress values at $\theta_p + 180^o$ (e.g. $\sigma_1, sigma_2$).

Finally,  you should understand that at $\theta_p + 90^o$ and $\theta_p + 270^o$ you would get the values in different order i.e $\sigma_2, sigma_1$).

---

If you understand the above, then for

- $\theta_s$ = The angle that plane of Max shear makes with horizontal measured anticlockwise

it shouldn't be too hard to understand that $\theta_{s,1} = \theta_p+45^o$ and $\theta_{s,2} = \theta_p-45^o$ would yield exactly the same values and they are almost identical ( $\theta_{s,1} = \theta_p+45^o$ and  $\theta_{s,3} = \theta_p+225^o$ are identical).